# How to remove duplicates before aggregating sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm struggling to get the correct points return value from a many to many through relationship. I have the tables `seasons`, `teams`, `drivers`, `results` and `driver_teams` with the relationship below

```rb
class Season < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :driver_teams
  has_many :drivers, through: :driver_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :driver_teams
end

class DriverTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :driver
  belongs_to :team

  has_many :results
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :driver_teams
  has_many :results, through: :driver_teams
end

class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :driver_teams
  has_many :results, through: :driver_teams
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :driver_team
  has_one :driver, though: :driver_team
  has_one :team, though: :driver_team
end
```

The `results` table has a points attribute that is just a simple interger field
I'm trying to get the sum of all points for each team within a seaon like below

```rb
season.teams.joins(:results).select('teams.*, SUM(results.points) AS points').group('teams.id')
```

But because a team can have multiple drivers using the `Driverteam` through table, these points are being duplicated by the number of drivers per team, since referencing `teams` from a season will return multiple teams within the through table.

The ideal result is to have `season.teams` return only the single instances of each team for a season.

Is there a way to prevent `season.teams` from returning duplicates of the teams before running an aggregate SQL function?
I've tried simply using  `season.teams.distinct` but the distinct statement appears to be run after the group by so its still including the duplicates during the calulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by just simply adding `driver_teams.id` into the group by clause

```rb
season.teams.joins(:results).select('teams.*, SUM(results.points) AS points').group('teams.id, driver_teams.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to select the distinct before and don't use the function `.distinct` of ruby. Do something like `(Select distinct seasons FROM..)`. It should leave you without duplicates.